# why use async task for logging in -- android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why is logging in typically an async task? It doesn't really seem necessary to me. I'm not really sure why android studio generates an async task for logging in when you have it generate a login activity for you.

Comment: because you cannot have any Connection on Main Thread. 
all internet connection should be in background. so you need to use AsyncTask.doInBackground()

Comment: One more thing  all long  running  operation no matter  network or other  operations like database  must be put in separate thread, otherwise it stuck UI of applications.